# amber diesel fuel

Tags: engine, diesel, fuel-consumption

Diesel fuel, initially of green-yeallowish, cider colour, stored outside in clear containers where the early sun reached it (my bad). During one month of storage it has now turned amber, cognac colour. Is it still safe for my engine to drink it ?

Answer (score 2):

Diesel and gasoline is often dyed in the US. Generally for tax purposes; eg, fuel for use in farm machinery does not pay road taxes, so it is not permitted to be used in cars( used on roads). The color dye gives a way to check. The dye is a miniscule amount in the fuel so a change of color is highly unlikely to cause problem.

Comment: If it was sitting in the sun, I can definitely see the dye getting bleached and/or changing color. I agree, there really shouldn't be any issue with using it.